# ANDROID Is it possible to only view a specific country in a google map?

Tags: android, dictionary

I'd like to create an application which only displays a single country. Upon clicking a specific place in a country like the Philippines, it has to display certain trivia. Asking if anyone of you already did something like this, or any idea/suggestion how to accomplish this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Google Maps do not support any direct way to display a country or any other geographical area.

The usual solution to this is to restrict the map viewport to some latlng range. An example solution would be to check the center of the map after drag/zoom. If the center gets outside the  bounds then scroll the map back to the edge of the bounds.

Comment: Depends if you want to use Google Maps Javascript API v3 in WebView (there are many SO questions answered) or native Google Maps Android API v2 (rather new API, not so many questions and answers).

Answer (score -1):

for any future visitors to this question, you can follow the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41880403/6732199

i hope it helps you .