# how to restrict maps to only one country using google maps api for android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I am totally new to google's maps api for android and I was wondering if it is possible to restrict the area the map is showing to one country only. I mean my target users are in my own country only and it is not useful nor logical to show them the whole world when the application logic is going to be only on this country.

Any ideas?

ps: if it is not possible in google's api,is there a way to do this with another api form another source which provides a mapping service?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are still interested, now it's possible to [restrict the user's panning to a given area](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#restricting_the_users_panning_to_a_given_area) using the `setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget` method.

You will need to update the dependencies for your Play Services:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
}
```

Comment: I will test it on my project. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

You can restrict the user view to specific square -maybe- of the map, to do so, you can use the following:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
// Create a LatLngBounds that includes the city of Adelaide in Australia.
private LatLngBounds ADELAIDE = new LatLngBounds(
  new LatLng(-35.0, 138.58), new LatLng(-34.9, 138.61));
// Constrain the camera target to the Adelaide bounds.
mMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(ADELAIDE);
```

in this case, the user will not be able to zoom in, in the map in areas where the camera is totally out of the range -square- you specified.

for more details, source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#restricting_the_users_panning_to_a_given_area

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you cannot only display your chosen country using the google api service. However, what you can do, is restrict google places auto complete to a specific country, by finding your country code (e.g. using this link https://countrycode.org/) and then adding the query to your google places api e.g.

```
components=country:your_country_code    //Insert code into example
```

For example, this is what is would look like:

```
  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?
input=bhubaneshwar&components=country:in&sensor=false&key=your_key
```

Answer (score 0):

out of the box this is not possible. However what you could theoretically do it find the max bounding box that shows the country in question then everytime the camera moves check to make sure the bounding box is inside the max one. If it is not set it to the max. that would restrict them to a certain spot

Answer (score 0):

you can override the map and specific the latitude and longitude
and zoom in with suitable for you and disable the gesture of map
see this example it is answered before

[limit scrolling and zooming Google Maps Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977078/limit-scrolling-and-zooming-google-maps-android-api-v2?answertab=votes#tab-top)