# Restrict a Service Within a Specific Area

Tags: mongodb, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geofencing, location-aware

Following is my scenario

1:  First i want to define a service offered in 3 particular areas. I want to save those areas in mongodb.(i don't know whether 1 area would be saved as one lat long value or an array of lat long )

2: i want to offer the service only to those users who exist in those areas where service has been offered.

Any suggestions for implementing this scenario and what google APIs would help me in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600087/how-to-restrict-maps-to-only-one-country-using-google-maps-api-for-android), you can restrict the user's panning to a given area using the `setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget` method. Here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#restricting_the_users_panning_to_a_given_area). Also from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818016/google-maps-v3-limit-viewable-area-and-zoom-level):

> You can listen to the `dragend` event, and if the map is dragged outside the allowed bounds, move it back inside. You can define your allowed bounds in a [`LatLngBounds`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds) object and then use the `contains()` method to check if the new lat/lng center is within the bounds.
>
> You can also limit the zoom level very easily.

Here are some related threads which might help:

- [How do I limit panning in Google maps API V3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125065/how-do-i-limit-panning-in-google-maps-api-v3)
- [Google Maps API 3 - limit pan/map bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099345/google-maps-api-3-limit-pan-map-bounds)